# Exception SIGABRT in dispatch_async _block_invoke for NSMutableDictionary setObject

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, crash, sigabrt

I observed no crash in my simulator runs but it is consistently happening on my iPhone (iOS 5.1) and iPad (iOS 6.1).

After much effort I symbolicated the crash to point the erroneous line in my code - here this symbolicated log goes:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  12

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x342fd29e 0x3423b000 + 795294
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3c17197a 0x3c169000 + 35194
2   CoreFoundation                  0x342fd1c0 0x3423b000 + 795072
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3425e864 0x3423b000 + 145508
4   MyApp                           0x0011626c __55-[MSCollectionViewController updateUI:]_block_invoke (MSCollectionViewController.m:385)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x3c58911a 0x3c587000 + 8474
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x3c58d95c 0x3c587000 + 26972
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x3c58dabc 0x3c587000 + 27324
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5bda0c 0x3c5b7000 + 27148
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5bd8a0 0x3c5b7000 + 26784
```

As anyone can guess, the error is on Line#385 of my MSCollectionViewController.m file. However I am still unable to see what could cause such a crash, as it runs fine on simulator.

**UPDATED CODE:**
Note that now it is crashing at `[m_photoArray addObject:photoDetailDict];`
I added `m_photoArray (NSMutableArray)` initialization for reference which I am doing on main thread.

Here is my code, including the problematic line # 385 as comment:

```
 __block NSString * flickrPhotoArrayPath = [Commons getFlickrJSONPathForMuseumURI:argURI];

if (m_photoArray)
{
    [m_photoArray removeAllObjects];
}
else
{
    m_photoArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}    


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0),
    ^{

        NSArray *arrayFromFlickrJSON = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:flickrPhotoArrayPath];

        if (!arrayFromFlickrJSON || [arrayFromFlickrJSON count]==0)
            return;
        if (bViewVisible)
        {
            [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Fetching Photos" maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];
        }

        for (id photo in arrayFromFlickrJSON)
        {
            NSDictionary * dict = (NSDictionary *)photo;
            NSMutableDictionary * photoDetailDict = [dict mutableCopy];  
            NSString * filePath = [photoDetailDict objectForKey:@"photoFilePath"];    
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

            [photoDetailDict setObject:image forKey:@"photoImage"]; 

            //AND HERE GOES THE CRASH!!!  
            [m_photoArray addObject:photoDetailDict];                 //Line 385
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if ([SVProgressHUD isActive])
                [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            //More code to update UI
        });
    });
```

Here goes my 2 questions:

- What is it in NSMutableDictionary setObject that I am seeing this crash?
- Why don't I observe it with same set of data on my simulator?

**UPDATE:**

Instantly found glitch in my code:

The issue maybe in `[photo mutableCopy];` - photo is of `id` type, not `NSDictionary`. I need to cast it to `NSDictionary` first before performing `mutableCopy`.

The major question still remains is - why simulator allows it?

Heck, why even compiler allows it?

Comment: Any case in which photoDetailDict is getting accessed/modified by some other thread?

Comment: I suppose it is freshly being created here using mutableCopy. So no, no such possibility.

Comment: Your update does not make sense. Casting an object to a different type does not change the object at runtime. I do not see how this could fix a crash.

Comment: How about adding assertions and error checks and stop guessing? For example, a container doesn't like to be set an object which is nil. Also, I would guess that ` [m_photoArray addObject:photoDetailDict];` is not safe regarding concurrent access.

Comment: @MartinR - but it could be that [id setObject] is failing due to not casting, isn't it?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper, you are right, I am adding them. Basically process from modifying to symbolicating is a long one because I am using remote mac so have to route through testflight. I am in for a lot of guesswork. What could be the alternative of addObject, m_photoArray being NSMutableArray?

Comment: My guess is, `image` is nil. Using the inappropriate `imageWithContentsOfFile:` for loading remote resources without checking for errors or at least bypassing the following code if it is nil calls for troubles. A still naive approach would at least use NSURLConnection's less inappropriate synchronous convenient method `synchronous load with request` (name forgotten on purpose) which provides an error parameter.

Comment: 'imagewithContentsOfFile' is the reason I am taking it to async queue. What other option did I have? image is not nil as same code works fine on simulator. Earlier I ran it on main thread (yes, main thread, and on both devices) and it loaded them correctly - but it only loaded them partially when I showed them in UI. I did not know exactly when it was done loading them, that's why I added this whole async approach after reading against sync approach for disk operations.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper - your assumption turned out to be correct. Due to mysterious reasons, it failed to load the file locally, so image was nil. If you could add as an answer I could accept it. Thank you so much.